# Colour LEDs construction

Tags: led, design

While making colourful LEDs why dont we just coat the LED with a filter to just give out the colour of the light we want , rather than constructing the LED with different combinations of semiconductor which would give out that light?

Comment: Probably because  covering it will reduce the brightness.

Comment: Are there any ways where we could counter the reduction in brightness?

Comment: Your system might work if the original light source has all colours and thus adding a filter will pass that one colour out. But LED light source is more or less monochromatic. There is no way a blue coat will make a red LED give out blue light.

Comment: Using noncoloured plastic, which means it has the color of the emitted LED, if you add colored plastic, by default, you get less light than before, unless the color of the plastic is the same as the emitted color, and the brightness is equal or less (as is the color).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters work by **removing** things.  To work like you want, you would need an LED that emits all colors.  That would be a white LED. You would then use a filter to only pass the color you want to see.

That is inefficient because you are throwing away most of the produced light.

It is also a problem because LEDs only emit a single color.

[There are **no** white LEDs.  All LEDs emit a single color that is dictated by the semiconductor material.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#White_LEDs_and_the_illumination_breakthrough)

Most of the white light emitting LEDs you see use blue LEDs and a phosphor that glows in other colors when illuminated with blue light.

The other way to make white light LEDs is to combine a red, a green, and a blue LED in one chip and light them in proportion to make white.

In any case, you can't filter the light from a simple LED.  All simple LEDs emit one color, and if you filter it out you get nothing.

Comment: Oh I guess we could use filters of different colour  to add to a particular colour and then get the colour we want ,but then making LEDs for a specific colour seems to be more logical.

Comment: You cannot **add** a color with a filter.

Comment: I mean the colour of the filter itself , Like suppose the LEDs give off a red colour and we use a coating of blue colour , what would be the final result? I know I am sounding dumb here but hold on this is interesting

Comment: The final result will be BLACK: no light!

Comment: If you have a red LED, and put it behind a blue filter, then you will see - nearly nothing.  Filters **remove** things.  A blue filter passes blue light only.  It will pass nearly nothing of a red LED.

Comment: Ah! yes gotcha!!

Answer (score 0):

Note that there IS a way to do this, not with a filter but with [quantum dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot#Quantum_dot_displays).  Where a filter basically turns the light it absorbs into heat, a quantum dot turns it into light of a particular wavelength.  (It is pretty much the same process as the LED itself except the energy for it is coming from shorter-wavelength light rather than electricity.)

It will still be less efficient than using an LED of the desired color, but it is done sometimes when the LED output would be filtered anyway (like a backlit display) or color uniformity is extremely important (like a microLED display).